# meaning of node egress, pod egress, node tx bytes and pod tx bytes in GKE metrics

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, networking, google-kubernetes-engine

I have made a cluster on GKE and I am trying to understand the meaning of the metrics given in the metrics explorer.
I have two pods running on the same node and one is sending traffic to the other through curl. The following is observed:

```
Egress bytes per pod = 0
Node bytes transmitted > Egress bytes per node 
Pod1 bytes transmitted + Pod2 bytes transmitted > Node bytes transmitted
```

It is not approximately greater, it is very significantly greater. So my question is, what exactly is the difference between egress and bytes transmitted? How exactly is the traffic routed when two pods on the same node communicate? Does it go through the node?
If I want to compute network percent use of a node, what goes in the numerator and denominator? The only bandwidth I can find is node egress bandwidth. In numerator, technically then it should be node egress but tx bytes is greater than egress, so I am confused. Again, if I want to find which pod is choking node's network, do I look at pod tx bytes or pod egress.

Tried sending multiple curl requests to generate traffic between the pods to understand the meaning of the metrics. Can't find much help on gcp docs.

Answer (score 0):

When two pods on the same node communicate within a Kubernetes cluster, the network traffic typically does not leave the node. It is routed internally within the node itself.
In Kubernetes, each pod gets its own unique IP address, and these IP addresses are reachable within the cluster. When two pods on the same node communicate, they can use these IP addresses directly, without the need for external routing.  
Egress refers to the network traffic leaving a pod or a node to communicate with external resources or other pods/nodes
Bytes generally refers to the total number of bytes sent or received by a pod. It can include both ingress and egress traffic. It represents the overall data transferred, regardless of the source or destination.